# When usng rows with LAPACKE_sgetrs, why must ldb=1 (instead of 3, instead of n)?

Tags: lapack

We want to solve x for Ax=b,

```
A=
0  2  3
1  1  -1
0  -1  1

b=
13
0
1

x=
1
2
3
```

The program below first writes `A=P*L*U`. It works with columns. It is something like:

```
 float a[3*3]={
0,1,0,       
2,1,-1,
3,-1,1
};
  float b[8]={
13,
0,
1  

lapack_int n=3,lda=3,ldb=3,nrhs=1,info,piv[3];

info= LAPACKE_sgetrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,n,n,a,lda,piv);

info= LAPACKE_sgetrs(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,'N',n,nrhs,a,lda,piv,b,ldb);
```

This works. Now I would like to program with rows:

```
 float a[3*3]={
   0,2,3,
   1,1,-1,
   0,-1,1
};
  float b[8]={
13,
0,
1  

lapack_int n=3,lda=3,ldb=1,nrhs=1,info,piv[3];

info= LAPACKE_sgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,n,n,a,lda,piv);

info= LAPACKE_sgetrs(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'N',n,nrhs,a,lda,piv,b,ldb);
```

My question is: why must `ldb=1` (instead of 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is due to the wrapper LAPACKE.

If `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR` is used, the wrapper almost directly calls `sgetrs()` of LAPACK, as shown in the [source of LAPACKE](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/d0e/lapacke__sgetrs__work_8c_source.html). Hence, the leading dimension `ldb` of the array `b` must be equal or higher than the number of rows of the matrix `a`, that is `n=3`. Therefore, the requirement is `LDB >= max(1,N)` as in [`sgetrs()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/sgetrs.f.html).

One the other hand, if `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR` is used, `b` is transposed. Consequently, the leading dimension of the array `ldb` is now related to the number of right hand sides `nrhs=1`. The requirement is now `LDB >= max(1,NRHS)` as tested on [line 59](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/d0e/lapacke__sgetrs__work_8c_source.html) : `if( ldb < nrhs )`. Then the array `b` and the matrix are transposed by calling `LAPACKE_sge_trans`. Finally, `sgetrs()` is called using `lbd=n` and the result is transposed back.

Comment: Compilcated! I think I stick with LAPACK_COL_MAJIOR. Could you explain me "leading dimension"? When is the leading dimension `ldb` not equal to n?

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFHY8_5.3.0/com.ibm.cluster.essl.v5r3.essl100.doc/am5gr_leaddi.htm for a definition of the leading dimension of a 2D array: "an increment that is used to find the starting point for the matrix elements in each successive column of the array."... " It must always be greater than or equal to m, the number of rows in the matrix". It can be greater than n if the columns are not contiguous in memory (but equally spaced). Actual situations where such a feature become really useful do not come to my mind...